# Missing operation_Name from app insights logs after creating new .NET 8 Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, .net-8.0

I created a new Azure Function with ".NET 8 Isolated" and moved my .NET 6 code over to the new files and noticed that App Insights is no longer logging operation_Name column in App Insights. (Note: when I moved the .NET 6 code over I am upgrading it to .NET 8.) I need this for convenient queries.

I was not able to get host.json or appsettings.json to properly configure the other App Insights settings so I did the configuration in C#:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureHostConfiguration(hostConfig =>
{
    [...]
})
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    [...]
})
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
    {
        LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
            == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
        if (defaultRule is not null)
        {
            options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
        }
    });
    logging.AddFilter("System.Net.Http.HttpClient", LogLevel.Warning);
})
.Build();
```

Any idea how I get operation_Name logged? I tried setting IncludeScopes but that made no difference. It looks like this may be a known issue that Microsoft didn't want to address: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1124 If there is a solution of manually adding the the operation_Name to each ILogger I'd be willing to do that too.

Comment: which `.NET 6` code you used `isolated` or `LTS`?

Comment: .NET 8 isolated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed as of now. I believe this was a framework bug.

Comment: I'm running both .net 6 and .net 8 functions and have the same problem with missing operation_Name for my custom log entries. Could you please expand your answer and share your settings of the Application Insights in jost.json and Program.cs? Which version of packages are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure function logs `operation_Name` is only available in `traces` logs where function is **executing** or **executed**, not in every information logs.

I have used `.NET 6 isolated` code in `.NET 8 Isolated` Azure function,

I am using sample HTTP Trigger.

[image]

**#Mycode:**
**`.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`OUTPUT`:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your csproj reads as you having a .net 6 application not .net 8 as is in my question.

Comment: @WildlyStunted You said you are using .net 6 code in your function.

Comment: Sorry that was poorly worded in my question and I will update it